# Javascript maximum call stack size exceeded fixed from removing function brackets

Tags: javascript, recursion, stack, call

when I  try to run the following code below :

```js
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    s.reverse();
    const findEndWord = (index) => {
        s[index] === ' ' || index === s.length ? index : findEndWord(index + 1);
    } 
    
    const reverseWord = (left, right) => {
        if(left >= right) {
            return;
        } 
        const temp = s[left];
        s[left] = s[right];
        s[right] = temp;
        reverseWord(left + 1, right -1);   
    }
    // code to actually implement
    var index = 0;
    while(index < s.length) {
    const end = findEndWord(index);
    reverseWord(index, end -1);
    index = end + 1;
    }
    return s;
};
```

i get that "Maximum call stack size exceeded" as an error.

However when I run the following code

```js
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    s.reverse();
    const findEndWord = (index) => 
    s[index] === ' ' || index === s.length ? index : findEndWord(index + 1); 
    
    
    const reverseWord = (left, right) => {
        if(left >= right) {
            return;
        } 
        const temp = s[left];
        s[left] = s[right];
        s[right] = temp;
        reverseWord(left + 1, right -1);   
    }
    // code to actually implement
    var index = 0;
    while(index < s.length) {
    const end = findEndWord(index);
    reverseWord(index, end -1);
    index = end + 1;
    }
    return s;
};
```

the code runs perfectly. The only difference between the two pieces of code is that the first function expression "findEndWord" is using curly braces but in the second piece of code I remove the curly braces from the findEndWord function expression. Isn't this just syntactical sugar? can someone explain why the maximum call stack size exceeded just from usage of curly braces? Thank you

Comment: In the second case the function actually returns something. In the first case it returns `undefined`. It is not just syntactic sugar. Omitting the curly braces basically adds an implicit `return` statement in front of the function body.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to start using a debugger to *observe* rather than *ask*.  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes and see the exact behavior and values of your variables.  When you debug these, where does the behavior first change?  (Hint: What is the value of `const end` in each?)

Comment: right after using my debugger, I see that the "end" variable is set to undefined because the findEndWord in the first example doesn't return anything. Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code block:

```js
const findEndWord = (index) => {
    s[index] === ' ' || index === s.length ? index : findEndWord(index + 1);
}
```

Your function does not return any value. You can fix that by adding `return`:

```js
const findEndWord = (index) => {
    return s[index] === ' ' || index === s.length ? index : findEndWord(index + 1);
}
```

On the second code block:

```js
const findEndWord = (index) => 
s[index] === ' ' || index === s.length ? index : findEndWord(index + 1);
```

The arrow symbol `=>` already does the job. So `f = (x) => x*2` is equal to `f = (x) => { return x*2; }`

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, the function doesn't return anything so it would keep going forever while in your second example the function does return something.